# Is there a syntax error with this SQL server query? Can I not use "target.@1"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hard coded, this works:

```
var insertCommand1 = ("MERGE INTO Leaderboard WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target USING (SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE WeekNumber = 7) AS Source ON (target.id = source.id) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.Id  = source.Id, target.Week7 = source.weeklyScore WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, Week7) VALUES (source.Id, source.weeklyScore);");

db.Execute(insertCommand1);
```

This does not work:

```
var insertCommand1 = ("MERGE INTO Leaderboard WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target USING (SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE WeekNumber = @0) AS Source ON (target.id = source.id) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.Id  = source.Id, target.@1 = source.weeklyScore WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, @2) VALUES (source.Id, source.weeklyScore);");

db.Execute(insertCommand1, weeknum, weekstring, weekstring);
```

The error says there's a syntax error near @1. What could this be?
I've already debugged to make sure the value to weeknum and weekstring were correct.

Working in SQL server on VS 2015.

Schema for the 2 tables-

```
Leaderboard(Id, Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5, 
                Week6, Week7, Week8, Week9, Week10) 
with Id as the primary key

Scores(Id, WeekNumber, weeklyScore) 
with Id and WeekNumber as the primary key
```

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
Show us some data and expected output and what are you trying to achive and we can help you more.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza just posted the schemas- hope this helps!

Comment: Jules your model looks should be normalized, `Leaderboard `should be `{Id, Week_id, Score}` then if you want show several week you use `PIVOT` That will allow you add remove weeks without change your db design.

Comment: Actually, after looking your `Scores` you dont need `Leaderboard` table. Just create a view using [**PIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) over `Scores`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the fieldname using a parameter, and @parameters are for values.

```
 , target.@1 = source.weeklyScore
```

Should be

```
 , target.something = @1
```

Comment: Oh okay. What's an alternative for this? That's a dynamic variable that changes and I need to be able to change what the query says

Comment: You can create a dynamic query instead. But again not sure what are you trying to achieve here. At first look your query doesn't seem logical, so we need db schema sample data and desire output to understand what you need.

Comment: You would have to replace the @1 in the string build with the name of the field you are examining, e.g.  `var insertCommand1 = ("MERGE INTO Leaderboard WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target USING (SELECT * FROM Scores WHERE WeekNumber = @0) AS Source ON (target.id = source.id) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.Id  = source.Id, target." & fieldNameVar & " = source.weeklyScore WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, @2) VALUES (source.Id, source.weeklyScore);");`

Comment: However, your query definitely has some flaws. Why would you update the ID? Why would the value from `weeklyscore` end up in differently named fields? How many different field names could it end up in, and are they all in one table? What does the data look like? All of this may be needed to provide you with an optimal answer, as opposed to one that simply answers the question you asked with no attempt to see if that is the best way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I had target.Week7 as target.@1 because Week7 is a column in Leaderboard. Based on the user's week choice (could be Week5, Week8, etc), that is the column of Leaderboard I want to pass the value from source.weeklyScore into.

Comment: Then you need use something like David suggest. Update the string query fields using `string.Format` and the parameters to avoid sqlInjection as you are using right now.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I guess don't have to update the ID, but it doesn't make a difference if I do because it will be the same anyways. I'm going to add the schemas to an edit of the question for you to check out. I needed to add this Leaderboard table last minute because I needed a specific schema for another part of the project. All it does is pull data from Scores and puts it in the new (and improved) schema.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use a parameter as a schema object name instead of a value.  This doesn't work, as you've discovered.  Parameters are just for values.

If you need a dynamic schema object name, be aware of two things:

1. It could impact performance, though probably not by much.
2. SQL injection is a significant concern.

The first one you can measure if it becomes a problem, but I doubt it will.  The second one can be handled just by being careful.  The simple rule with SQL injection is not to always use parameters for everything, but to never execute user-modified values as code.

For schema objects, you already have a finite set of possible values.  So you can build a list of known values in your code.  This isn't user-modified, so it's safe.  (Maybe it's hard-coded, maybe you auto-generate it from the DB schema, that's up to you.)

With the variable, check if it matches a value in the list.  If it doesn't, that's an error and the code should simply raise the appropriate exception or in some other way handle that error case.  If it does match an element from the known finite list of safe non-user-modifiable values, use that matched value from the list in your query:

```
var query = string.Format("SELECT SomeTable.{0} FROM SomeTable ...", knownList[x]);
```

(Or however you want to structure it, hopefully you get the idea.)

Then with that dynamically generated query, you can add your parameter values and you're all set.

Comment: I dont see how could impact sql performance,  Is just building a string before sending to db. But very good way to handle the `knowList` of valid input to avoid sql Injection.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: It *probably* won't impact performance, and if so only negligibly.  I'm thinking along the lines of the various systems in play caching queries and execution plans and whether or not a dynamically built string may impact that.  I can't guarantee that it wouldn't.